# Do infinitesimal neighbourhoods help to compute the inverse images of coherent sheaves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $i:Z\to X$ be a closed embedding of (projective) varieties; $S$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$. How could one compute $H^*(Z,i^\ast S)$ (I don't know whether I should write $H^\ast (Z,i^{-1}S)$ instead? If there is a substantial distinction, I could be interested in both)? Could one do this using some infinitesimal neighbourhoods of $Z$ in $X$?

Comment: Take $Z=x$ to be a point and $S=\mathcal{O}_X$, then $H^0(i^*S)=k$ and $H^0(i^{-1}S)=\mathcal{O}_x$. So they  are certainly different.
Computing $H^∗(Z,i^∗S)$  is not so easy in general, and usually it is more useful to resolve the ideal sheaf than to play with inf. nbhds
I'm not quite sure what else to say.

Comment: Could you say more about resolutions? For which $S$ the computation of $H^\ast(Z,i^*S)$ is easy?! Thank you!

Comment: For example, if $X$ is projective space then  Hilbert's syzygy
theorem would allow you to resolve the ideal of $Z$ by graded
free modules. This means that the ideal sheaf could be resolved by
sums of line bundles. You could compute cohomology of 
$H^*(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)$ using this.